# React auth and conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-hooks

I want to check the authorization for rendering components, but now useEffect only works there when the page is first rendered or restarted because it has a dependency [ ]. At the same time, I get only the state (name) after authorization, the other states do not change until the page is restarted later. I tried to specify a dependency on [ session ] in useEffect , but since after receiving the session , it is not visible in useState before restarting , then useEffect does not work.

> I know this is a bit of a stupid question, it's just that I get the
> state at the time of rendering the page, but how can I change it
> without completely re-rendering the entire page. I have to change only
> the menu to page header after authorization

Page :

```
function MainPage() {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false); 
  const { session, loading, name } = useCheckCookieToken();

  useEffect(() => {
    let cancel = false;
    async function start() {
      if (session) {
        setNameUser(name)
        setAuth(true)
      } else {
        setAuth(false)
        setNameUser('')
      }
    }
    start()

    return () => {
      cancel = true;
    };
  }, [session]);

return (
    <>
      {
        loading ? (
          <div><CircularProgress /></div>
        ) : auth ? (
          <>
            <UserBar setShowModal={setShowModal} nameUser={nameUser} setShowModalCatalog={setShowModalCatalog} setAuth={setAuth} />
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Bar setShowModal={setShowModal} setShowModalCatalog={setShowModalCatalog} />
          </>
        )
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

Api:

```
export function useCheckCookieToken() {
  const [session, setSession] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [role, setRole] = useState('');

  const checkCookieToken = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`/api/checkCookie`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
      });

      if (res.ok) {
        const result = await res.json();
        setSession(result.user.id);
        setName(result.user.name);
        setRole(result.user.role);
        setLoading(false);
      } else {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let cancel = false;

    checkCookieToken();

    return () => {
      cancel = true;
    };
  }, [checkCookieToken]);


  useEffect(() => {
    let cancel = false;

    checkCookieToken();

    return () => {
      cancel = true;
    };
  }, [session]);


  return { session, loading, role, name };
}
```

**In the api, I get all the values, but from them on the page I get only the user's nickname without reloading**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance, I see several issues which might be responsible:

#### On `Mainpage`

- The `useEffect` dependencies should be `[session != null`, name], b/c this the values the callback depends on.
- `cancel` doesn't seem to do anything, and I'm not sure what you want to achieve with that construction anyway. It looks like you took it from some kind, maybe you can link that to explain what you're trying to achieve?
- If you're not using React 18, calling `setState()` subsequently will cause multiple rerenders. You might want to to utilize `unstable_batchedUpdate` from `react-dom`. But can't you just drop `auth` and check for something like `!!name`?

#### In `useCheckCookieToken`

- The `useEffect` dependencies look rather obscure: The same `usEffect` under another, just with different dependencies, and `session` isn't required for the callback. What do you try to achieve? To you have a reference?
- As in the other file: `cancel` doesn't achieve anything